# Apply positive and negative voltage to component using single power supply

Tags: voltage, negative, negative-voltage

I have an electromagnet and a 12V power supply.
I would like to apply +12V to the electromagnet at some times and -12V at other times.

My current thought is to use four transistors (two NPN, two PNP) in a matrix (see diagram).
I have two concerns:

1. When all four transistors are open, the "inside" leads will be floating. Is this a problem? If so, would a pulldown resistor on the "inside" sides mitigate it?
2. Using two transistors (one each side) would be cheaper and take up less space, but I can't figure out a way to do it (even with diodes) that doesn't short out the power supply. Is there an easy way to do this (besides adding a second -12V supply)?

Thanks!

[image: Four-transistor matrix]

Comment: The name for what you're trying to build is an 'H-Bridge'.

Comment: Re: 1. you must  never allow that to happen (shorted), and the answer to 2. is, no, I'm pretty sure you need four transistors.

Comment: If you don't need a lot of power at the output, a simpler and smaller solution could be to use a mosfet gate driver as the H bridge. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/278645/how-to-generate-a-bipolar-waveform-using-mosfet/278812#278812.

Comment: @brhans thank you, that is what I'm looking for! I feel silly now.

Comment: @MarcusMüller (out of curiosity) why would putting all four transistors in the "open" state cause a short?